# How to work with ImageButton in code behind in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            string path = Server.MapPath("~//Images//" + FileName);
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(path);
            string imagepathsource = path;
            string imagepathdest = @"D:\\" + Session["brandname"].ToString() + "\\" + Seasonfolders.SelectedItem.Text + "\\" + stylefolders.SelectedItem.Text + "\\Images\\" + FileName;
            File.Move(imagepathsource, imagepathdest);

            uploadedimage.ImageUrl = "D://" + Session["brandname"].ToString() + "//" + Seasonfolders.SelectedItem.Text + "//" + stylefolders.SelectedItem.Text + "//Images//" + FileName;
        }
    }
```

uploadedimage is a ImageButton where I need to display the image using imageurl with that link. The image is not displaying and no error.. I could see when the above code gets execute the page is getting refreshed? What code can be added in this ??

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: `ASP.NET` controls will not allow absolute paths. It should with wrt server url

Comment: @ThanosMarkou No Exceptions ... Just executes with no output ...

Comment: @Bharadwaj So how to access the filepath from E: to D:

Comment: @Sriram Flies which you want to display on a page to user, should be under application folder, if you want files to open and process in code, then those can be accessed through absolute path.

Comment: Yeah @Bharadwaj your right. Its open and the imageURL got its link to point with the filename. The image is not been displayed. Y so??? ImageURL accessed its directories in right way by the code I mentioned ??? why I couldn't see the image which is in different folder though I used absolute paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ImageUrl` needs an URL.

So instead of assigning it with a local file name on disk, use something like this (where `~` stands for 'application root folder':

```
uploadedimage.ImageUrl = "~/Images/yourImage.png"
```

You have to supply it with:

- An image inside your application root folder;
- An URL that is catched by a HttpHandler, that generates / loads the image from a different location (a little harder to do, but if you need to load from another location then inside application root, this is the best option).

Comment: I stuck with accessing folders... I kept my application in folders like this .../Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/Application... How to map again to the folder1... its showing path is not valid